# Is there a way to bind the source code of a reference in VisualStudio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference

I have this reference which comes from another project in my same machine.

It is cumbersome to jump from one project to another each time I need to see the source code.

Does Visual Studio have any way to specify where the source code for a given dll is so I can see it?

Comment: if your referenced project is only used for your primary project, then just add that referenced project to your solution.

Comment: We have this solution _Clients_ and the referenced project is in another called _Services_ I guess I could create a new solution containing both ...

Comment: It is up to you, as always.  Just be careful, though, because that solution will create copies of a code base, which is the origin of many headaches.  Another solution is to use version control, such as SVN or Team Foundation Server.

Comment: I might include existing projects from their original location. My concern is the memory consumption.